When does coroutine in asyncio actually cedes the execution?
I am trying to do a deep dive into Python's asyncio module. I understand we need to await the coroutine to get their results and when we await any coroutine, the surrounding coroutine cedes its execution to the event loop and lets any other coroutine run which is ready for execution.
Consider the following example:
async def parse_data(idx,pool):
    await compute_and_fetch_data()
    # Do some work


async def compute_and_fetch_data(idx, pool):
    # Do some CPU intensive task such as a complex compuation and produce the query to be executed
    
    #Hardcoding query for demonstration
    query = "SELECT * FROM customers" 
    async with pool.acquire() as conn:
        async with conn.cursor() as cur:
            await cur.execute(query)
            result = await cur.fetchall()
            logger.info(f"Fetched result for query {idx+1} successfully.")
            return result

async def main():
    pool = await aiomysql.create_pool(host='localhost', user='user', password='password', db='laundry')
    asyncio.gather(parse_data(1, pool))

asyncio.run(main())
    

Inside the parse_data coroutine, we are awaiting the compute_and_fetch_data coroutine. I have added a placeholder to represent some computations that compute_and_fetch_data will be doing before executing a query on the database. As computing is a CPU-intensive task and executing a query is an IO-bound task, will the parse_data coroutine cede its execution as soon as it reaches the await compute_and_fetch_data code block or will it do the computations inside the compute_and_fetch_data first and cede the execution when it reaches the stage where it needs to execute the query on the database(a time-consuming process) ?
If the latter is true, is it still valid to say that the surrounding coroutine cedes its execution when it reaches the await keyword?


when we await any coroutine, the surrounding coroutine cedes its execution to the event loop and lets any other coroutine run which is ready for execution

This is not exactly correct. See below.

is it still valid to say that the surrounding coroutine cedes its execution when it reaches the await keyword?

The answer is no, not for coroutines themselves. When you await a coroutine, it actually blocks the current task. Let's test this:
import asyncio

async def print_message(message: str):
    print(message)

async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    await queue.get()
    await print_message("This will not run until the above get returns")

asyncio.run(main())

When asyncio.run is called, it creates a task to run the coroutine main, but there is only one task. So when you await queue.get(), it blocks the task. It would yield to other tasks running on the event loop, but in this case, there are no other tasks. If we cancel this with ctrl + c, then the following exception is raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 684, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\<user>\Documents\GitHub\pyside-asyncio-prototype\prototype\test.py", line 10, in main
    await queue.get()
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\queues.py", line 158, in get
    await getter
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

You can see here that it is the await queue.get() that got canceled.

If we adjust our test program to:
import asyncio

async def print_message(message: str):
    print(message)

async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    await asyncio.gather(
        queue.get(),
        print_message("This will print because the task is concurrent"),
    )

asyncio.run(main())

then the following gets printed out:
> python test.py
This will print because the task is concurrent

Of course, the program blocks because it is still awaiting the queue.get(). The reason that the message gets printed out is that asyncio.gather launches each of its arguments, which can be coroutines or tasks, as tasks if they are not already tasks. In our case, both queue.get and print_message (with their complete arguments) are coroutines, so they get launched as concurrent tasks.

So the key concept to understand in asyncio is the difference between a coroutine and a task. You can think of coroutines as the basic building blocks of an asyncio program, but it is tasks that allow things to run concurrently. When you await in a coroutine inside a task, it yields to other tasks. That's what allows concurrency in asyncio. Coroutines are all actually running sequentially, because the asyncio event loop is single-threaded, but when a task encounters await, it yields execution to other tasks. When a coroutine that performs an I/O operation is awaited, that's when you "gain" performance in asyncio, because Python will hand off the I/O operation to the operating system, which will spread the operation(s) across any core it desires before handing the computation back to Python. While the I/O is performing its computation outside of Python, the await is blocking the current task, and this is what allows other tasks to do some work while that particular await's I/O is running via some operating system library.

So, in my example, it will yield execution to other tasks when the task encounters await fetch_and_compute_data() but since fetch_and_compute_data has some computational work at the beginning, it won't be of much help. Those computations will get executed when the event loops put this task back in execution. Is this correct ?

As far as I can see, none of your code will run concurrently. There is only one single task launched on the event loop, so every await will block that task until the awaitable returns. asyncio.gather only launches one task, and I don't see any other tasks launched within the code, although that depends upon the specifics of the underlying libraries. Any CPU bound (i.e., computational) work will block the entire event loop and every task. It is only await that yield to other tasks, but the awaits still block the task they run on.

I would read the task sections of the asyncio documentation. The TaskGroup documentation helps explain how tasks allow code to run concurrently.

Also, use the asyncio logging instead of the regular logger. You need to use logging.getLogger("asyncio") to get the asyncio logger.

Yes - the await keyword, along with the async with and async for statements, are the points, and then, where other concurrent tasks are allowed to run in the same event-loop.
For completeness, note however that the expression to the right of await is evaluated first - in this case, you have a co-routine function call there: that call returns a co-routine object, in  a synchronous way, and very efficiently - no code is executed inside the co-routine function at this step. It is just when resolving the await itself that the code inside the co-routine (compute_and_fetch_data, in this case) is actually executed - and along with it, other waiting tasks can also take steps. Once the code in the co-routine starts, it will run alone on the asyncio loop thread, without being interrupted up to the resolution of the first async with code inside it. So, note that the computations you replaced with a placeholder will effectivelly block any other async code to run. The usual approach for that is to refactor the computational code into another, synchronous, function and use await asyncio.run_in_executor(...) for it. (Note that Python having the GIL still can make your code run in sub-optimal ways: the asyncio loop will be free to step other tasks, but if the computation code is pure Python code, one of the two threads will be actually running. This time, the workaround would be to check your executor code and see if it is worth to use a ProcessPoolExecutor instead of the default ThreadPoolExecutor   asyncio uses - there are trade-offs in the resources needed to launch the workers and serialization of the data to be computed on one one hand, and capability to run truly parallel code by leveraging other CPU cores, which multi-processing allows.
